# How to split string into numerics and alphabets using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to split a string like "001A" into "001" and "A"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string[] data = Regex.Split("001A", "([A-Z])");
data[0] -> "001"
data[1] -> "A"
```

Comment: String.Split doesn't take a regex, as far as I know.

Comment: Did you test it? It should be `Regex.Split("001A", "([A-Z])")`, or the group is removed (as a divider).

Comment: this works, but it gives a string array of 3 elements. the last element is empty.

Answer (score 4):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(s, @"^(\d+)(.+)$");
string numeral = match.Groups[1].Value;
string tail = match.Groups[2].Value;
```

Comment: `.` matches anything, you should restrict to `\w` or `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: @knittl - I know, `.` is ok as long as the OP doesn't need to validate it. The question doesn't have enough details so I went with this.

Comment: the title of the question is »how to split numerics and _alphabets_« ;) but nevermind, in the given example your solution will give correct results

Answer (score 2):

This is Java, but it should be translatable to other flavors with little modification.

```
    String s = "123XYZ456ABC";
    String[] arr = s.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    // prints "[123, XYZ, 456, ABC]"
```

As you can see, this splits a string wherever `\d` is followed by a `\D` or vice versa. It uses [positive and negative lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find the places to split.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is as simple|complicated as your 001A sample, your should not be using a Regex but a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this to retrieve the integers from the string:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d*");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(inputString);
for(int i=0; i < matches.count;i++){
    sb.Append(matches[i].value + " ");
}
```

Then change the regex to match on characters and perform the same loop.

Answer (score 0):

And if there's more like `001A002B` then you could

```
    var s = "001A002B";
    var matches = Regex.Matches(s, "[0-9]+|[A-Z]+");
    var numbers_and_alphas = new List<string>();
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        numbers_and_alphas.Add(match.Value);
    }
```