# Remove alphabets from a string

Tags: c#

I want to remove alphabets from a string. What is the best way to do it. To be more precise, i have MAC address of a system, and I want to extract only the numbers from it. I have found this article or stackoverflow. [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645960/how-to-split-string-into-numerics-and-alphabets-using-regex)

I want to know, if using the regex is the best way or there are other ways to do it (maybe using LINQ).

Comment: Do you want the result to be the digits or the letters?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is this scenario for needing to remove the letters from a MAC address?

Comment: I have started working on DICOM files, and there are tools that let you modify the properties in those file. I am trying to change "StudyInstanceUID" in that. I wanted to generate a new "StudyInstanceUID" and the DICOM standard does not allow (atleast thats my understanding) for letters in "StudyInstanceUID".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the digits, you can use this regex:

```
var digits = Regex.Replace(text, @"\D", "");
```

`\D` matches anything that is not a digit, so removing those will give you the remaining digits.

Comment: Does \D includes + or = it is getting replaced too :-/

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ approach would be as follows:

```
string input = "12-34-56-78-9A-BC";
string result = new String(input.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Non-LINQ / 2.0 approach:

```
string result = new String(Array.FindAll(input.ToCharArray(),
                    delegate(char c) { return Char.IsDigit(c); }));
```

Comment: I was just going to update my answer with something similar. Thanks.

Comment: @Brian thanks, I'm perfectly happy with the regex approach too.

Answer (score 0):

This will replace anything that's not a number and leave you with just numbers:

```
        string text = "abc123abc:13sdf2";
        string numbers = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^\d]+", "");
        Console.WriteLine(numbers);
```